# how to get a string with double quotes and split it in jmeter

Tags: regex, string, jmeter, beanshell

I have the following string that is being returned from a regex extractor in a HTTP request.

```
issuerLogo2=,"issuerText":"humanaillinoishmo","networkType":"HMO","networkKey":"58288-ILN002","planScore":0.0,"rawOutOfPocketCost":0.0,"outOfPocketEstimate":0.0,"premiumBeforeCredit":231.29,"annualPremiumBeforeCredit":2775.48,"aptc":0.0,"totalContribution":0.0,"premiumAfterCredit":231.29,"annualPremiumAfterCredit":2775.48,"costSharingReductions":0.0,"adjustedOop":0.0,"oopMax":6300.0,"childOopMax":null,"maxTotalHealthCareCost":0.0,"estimatedTotalHealthCareCost":5075.48,"costSharing":null,"deductible":6100,"intgMediDrugDeductible":null,"medicalDeductible":4600,"drugDeductible":1500,
```

I would like to use the split this string to get values of all the attributes such as issuerText , networkType etc.

I am using beanshell sampler like

```
 vars line = vars.get(${issuerLogo2});
 String line = vars.get(${issuerLogo2});
 String line = vars.get("${issuerLogo2}");
```

etc.. i am getting error saying encountered '' Encountered "( ,"   or '' Encountered "\issuer\" ..

How do I escape the double quotes in the above string and get the issuerLogo2 value to a variable or another string in beanshell to split the string to get values of each attribute???

can someone pls help me on this ?

Comment: Are the fields always the same, or are you expecting different ones?

Comment: fields are always the same.. the values keep changing...

Answer (score 0):

The correct Beanshell statement will look like:

```
String line = vars.get("issuerLogo2");
```

`vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance `hence vars.get()` method expects **variable name**, and you're trying to pass variable value to it.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Comment: I am trying to assign a string A to another string variable B without being able to change the initial string variable A. at the same time escape the double quotes in string A while assigning it to B. :-|